# stream audio/video files from gridFS on the browser

Tags: php, mongodb, gridfs

I have been trying to read an audio file from mongoDB which i have stored using GridFS. I could download the file in the system and play from it but I wanted to stream those audio/video files from the DB itself and play it in the browser. Is there anyway to do that without downloading the file to the system? Any help would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP GridFS support has a [MongoGridFSFile::getResource()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mongogridfsfile.getresource.php) function that allows you to get the stream as a *resource* - which doesn't load the whole file in memory. Combined with `fread/echo` or [stream_copy_to_stream](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-copy-to-stream.php) you can prevent the whole file from being loaded in memory. With stream_copy_to_stream, you can simply copy the GridFSFile stream's resource to the STDOUT stream:

```
<?php
$m = new MongoClient;
$images = $m->my_db->getGridFS('images');

$image = $images->findOne('mongo.png');

header('Content-type: image/png;');
$stream = $image->getResource();

stream_copy_to_stream( $stream, STDOUT );
?>
```

Alternatively, you can use `fseek()` on the returned `$stream` resource to only send back parts of the stream to the client. Combined with [HTTP Range requests](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p5-range-latest.html), you can do this pretty efficiently.

Comment: Hey Derick. I tried getting the audio to play but in vain. I already wrote the above code to match my code still i get a player but not the file to play. Can you please help me out?

Comment: I get the file playing but cannot skip which is done by seek(file_handle,length). My question is if the user clicks on the timeline of the player then how do i take care of the offset of the place he clicked?

Comment: @user2610503 You will need to hook in a rest interface into your app which can take the flash/html5 representation is requesting skipping from the file

Comment: @Sammaye thanks for the response. I even ran into this nginx while trying to search for a solution to get my streaming done without using an external streaming app. So does that nginx server help in doing so? Coz am running php in apache.

Comment: @user2610503 Nginx might be better suited here if I am honest, I believe it actually has a plugin for this as well like: https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module so it could be a route to go

Comment: @Sammaye This is the code i have been using $stream = $file->getResource();
    while (!feof($stream)) { echo fread($stream, 8192); }  but it only downloads the file to my system if i use content type as 'audio/mpeg' and plays the whole file in the browser if content type is given as 'audio/mpeg3'. I want to play the file using a html5 audio tag. Please help me out.

Comment: @user2610503 This is really starting to be a whole other question about html5 usage

Comment: @Sammaye I am sorry to trouble you on changing my implementation plans. I am a complete rookie in this subject and I really need to learn a way to retrieve audio/video from mongodb GridFS and then use it in making an API for streaming from a phone application. Please suggest some way I can do this

Comment: @user2610503 I would suggest making a new question based around this since it requires a fair amount of work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206715/build-an-api-for-streaming-audio-video-from-gridfs-mongodb This is the link I have posted further queries to for this post. If you have solutions please do answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the [other recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18185601) fails, for example with `NginX` and `php-fpm`, because `STDOUT` is not available in `fpm`, you can use

```
fpassthru($stream);
```

instead of

```
stream_copy_to_stream( $stream, STDOUT );
```

So a complete solution looks like:

```
function img($nr)
{
  $mongo = new MongoClient();
  $img = $mongo->ai->getGridFS('img')->findOne(array('metadata.nr'=>$nr));
  if (!$img)
    err("not found");

  header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');
  header("Content-type: ".$img->file["contentType"]);
  header("Content-length: ".$img->getSize());
  fpassthru($img->getResource());

  exit(0);
}
```

FYI:

In this example:

- File is not acccessed by the filename, instead it is accessed by a number stored in the metadata.  Hint: You can set an unique index to ensure, that no number can be used twice.
- Content-Type is read from GridFS, too, so you do not need to hardcode this.
- NginX caching is switched off to enable streaming.

This way you can even handle other things like video or html pages.  If you want to enable NginX caching, perhaps only output `X-Accel-Buffering` on bigger sizes.