# build an API for streaming audio/video from GridFS mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, gridfs

I have tried the solution given in the link [stream audio/video files from gridFS on the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185390/stream-audio-video-files-from-gridfs-on-the-browser)

Still when I use my code the file gets downloaded or it plays with the default browser player.
My code is as:

```
header('Content-type: audio/mpeg;');

$stream = $file->getResource();
while (!feof($stream)) {
      echo fread($stream, 8192);
      }
```

I actually want a solution to build an API so that I can retrieve the audio/video from mongodb GridFS and play it streaming from a phone application.

Help is urgently needed. Any help on the topic would be welcome.

Comment: You may want to include that you wish for it to work with a HTML widget of sorts, maybe if you have found one it would be good to place it here

Comment: Yeah thank you so much @Sammaye. I would be glad to have any solution on streaming the audio,video from GridFS, and much better if the streaming can be used in HTML5 widgets (audio,video).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make an API for playing the file straight from the mongoDB GridFS in a HTML audio video image widget. The only problem with it is that it uses the data retrieved from mongoDB as a base64 data. Now the problem that i am talking about is discussed in this link:

http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/when-to-base64-encode-images-and-when-not-to.

I hope you find that useful before deciding to use the solution I am using. My solution is as follows:

```
$stream = $file->getResource();
$stringcoded = stream_get_contents($stream); //converts the stream to string data
$encoded = base64_encode($stringcoded);  //encodes string data to base64
```

Now that you have the audio, video or image data encoded in base64, you just have to echo the data in the 'src' portion of the html5 widget.

I got this solution from a very useful blog. If you need more help on it please go through it:

http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/09/html5/html5-media-and-data-uri

Any enhanced solution to this problem is more than welcome.