# Can I serve media to web browser from MongoDB

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

I will try to keep this simple without lots of extra information. I have been investigating MongoDB and I believe it will work well for my next project. There is one thing I am fuzzy about though: storing and retrieving files (chunks) from GridFS.

Lets take a CMS for example. If I wanted to display (output via the browser) an image, I would go my MySQL database, find the key and pull the metadata that would include the file source on the File System and then display an image tag with that href. I know that I can store image/video/etc files in Mongo beautifully and I can retrieve binary, but if I wanted to display that file (push it to the browser) would I have to write the contents to a temporary file and then echo my img tag with the href? That can't be more efficient.

I feel like I'm missing something. For this circumstance, is MongoDB any better?

For clarification: I'm using PHP and Apache on a typical LAMP stack (development not production) and working on a platform to enable creative collaboration between artists. So, I would have several artists collaborating on the same files, and I would like to be able to search inside those files, index them, keep all metadata together and employ sharding. I really seems like MongoDB is the way to go.

Thanks!

Michael

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185390/stream-audio-video-files-from-gridfs-on-the-browser

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store binary files in the database, you can serve them directly without writing them to a filesystem first. All you have to do is write a PHP script (or whatever) to send the data in response to an incoming HTTP request, with the proper [media type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) in the response HTTP header.

So if we're talking about images, in your HTML you'd do something like this:

```
<img src="/your_img_script.php?image=1234"></img>
```

Then just write `your_img_script.php` to lookup image ID 1234 and dump the data out with a `image/jpeg` (or whatever) content type header.